# UserDetailsService with multi table

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-security

I have two tables admin and user, but in the UserDetailsService there are one method called loadUserByUsername, I made this to check the admin or user and load the data, but there are issue with that if the user and admin have the same username ( 2 tables ), how can I do it?

```
@Override
public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String login) throws UsernameNotFoundException {

    if (isValidEmailAddress(login)) {
        Admin admin = adminRepository.findByEmail(login);
        if (admin != null) {
            return new User(admin.getUsername(), admin.getPassword(), getAuthorities(admin.getRoles()));
        }

        Customer customer = customerRepository.findByEmail(login);

        if (customer != null) {
            return new User(customer.getUsername(), customer.getPassword(), getAuthorities(customer.getRoles()));
        }
    } else {
        Admin admin = adminRepository.findByUsername(login);
        if (admin != null) {
            return new User(admin.getUsername(), admin.getPassword(), getAuthorities(admin.getRoles()));
        }

        Customer customer = customerRepository.findByUsername(login);

        if (customer != null) {
            return new User(customer.getUsername(), customer.getPassword(), getAuthorities(customer.getRoles()));
        }
    }

    throw new UsernameNotFoundException("username not found");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If this is still an option for you, it might be best to migrate all users into the same table so that duplicates are not possible. Their role can be distinguished in a `role` column or a related `roles` table.

If not, it will depend on how you tell whether or not an admin is logging in.

Some applications will do this by URL. For example, admins will log in using an endpoint like `/admin/login` and others will use `/user/login`. Generally, though, something from the request must give your system a hint as to what kind of user it is. To achieve this in Spring Security, consider using [`AuthenticationManagerResolver` and a custom filter](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-security-authenticationmanagerresolver).